# EI click on submit button from powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble with submitting the form, the button doesn't have an ID or anything I can use or know how to use. Here is the code:

```
$url = "https://www.confessout.com/hi" 
$message="anonymous message"
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000} 
$ie.Document.getElementById("message").value = $message 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
$ie.Document.getElementByClassName('special big')[0].click
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10000
$ie.quit
```

Comment: Maybe just tell the form to submit? `$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument2_forms[0].submit()` or find the element that looks like the Send Message button and use that: `$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument2_forms[0].elements[2].click()`

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly